# En Python 3x y Pandas¿Cómo extraer el valor numérico de una columna que contiene datos en diferentes formatos?

Tags: python, pandas

En el siguiente DataFrame deseo obtener de las columnas 'Porc Ing 1', 'Porc Ing 2' y 'Porc Ing 3', el valor numérico (enetero) de cada valor.

```
datos = pd.DataFrame({'producto':['producto 1','producto 2','producto 3','producto 4' ], 'porc Ing 1':['100', '40.0% / +-5%','40.0%',''],
                 'porc Ing 2':['0', '40.0% / +-5%','40.0%','100'], 
                 'porc Ing 3':['0', '20.0% / +-5%','20.0%','']})
datos.set_index('producto')
```

Debe notarse los siguientes casos:

1. el valor '40.0% / +- 5%', solo debe aparecer 40 en formato entero
2. el valor 100, a este no le tiene que hacer nada solo convertirlo de string a entero
3. registros vacios o '', a estos rellenarlos con un CERO
4. registros con el valor '40.0%', solo quitar el signo de % y convertirlo de string a entero

   Gracias por su aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que quieres hacer esto para todos los valores de todas las celdas de tu dataframe (todas las filas y todas las columnas), la solución recomendada sería:

1. Escribe una función que reciba como parámetro el contenido de una celda (que es una cadena) y devuelva como resultado el número que debería corresponderle.
2. Aplica esa función a todas las celdas con `dataframe.applymap(funcion)`

Para la escritura de esa función puedes usar cualquier funcionalidad estándar Python, como `startswith()`, etc. Pero en este caso particular todo parece resolverse fácilmente con una expresión regular, ya que en el fondo los cuatro casos que enumeras se reducen a dos:

1. Si la celda está vacía, su valor es cero
2. Si no está vacía, es el primer número que aparezca en ella, hasta encontrar el primer carácter no-dígito (ya sea este un punto, o un `%`), convertido a `int`.

La opción 2 la captura la expresión regular `\d+` pues `\d` significa "cualquier número" y `+` significa "una o más veces".

Así pues, la siguiente función hace la transformación deseada:

```
import re
def extraer_numero(celda):
    m = re.match(r"\d+", celda)
    if m:
      # Si hubo coincidencia, m.group() devuelve el texto que coincidió
      # Basta convertirlo en entero
      return int(m.group())
    else:
      # Si no hubo coincidencia (lo que ocurre también en celdas vacías)
      # el valor a retornar es cero
      return 0
```

Y se aplica a tu dataframe así:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = pd.DataFrame({'producto':['producto 1','producto 2','producto 3','producto 4' ], 'porc Ing 1':['100', '40.0% / +-5%','40.0%',''],
                 'porc Ing 2':['0', '40.0% / +-5%','40.0%','100'], 
                 'porc Ing 3':['0', '20.0% / +-5%','20.0%','']})
datos.set_index('producto').applymap(extraer_numero)
```

Resultado:

```
            porc Ing 1  porc Ing 2  porc Ing 3
producto                                      
producto 1         100           0           0
producto 2          40          40          20
producto 3          40          40          20
producto 4           0         100           0
```

Si en vez de aplicarse a toda la tabla quisieras hacerlo a una sola columna, también puedes, así:

```
datos["porc Ing 3"] = datos["porc Ing 3"].map(extraer_numero)
```

Comment: Gracias. Fue muy útil